# page_fan query not returning results

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have authorized my app and made sure it gets 'user_likes' permissions.
When I execute this query:

```
select uid from page_fan where uid='&lt;uid here>'
```

This is the result:

> <fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true"/>

What do I need to check? What am I missing?

Comment: And yes, I have made sure I have "liked" several pages.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is asking for the user id, but you already know it. I believe your intention was to do the following:

```
select page_id from page_fan where uid={uid here}
```